# How to announce SwiperJS slide contents with VoiceOver?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, swiper.js, web-frontend

I am using the SwiperJS react component and would like to announce the slide contents when they come into view using VoiceOver.  Is there a way to do this?  Right now users hear no feedback when clicking the next or previous buttons.

Here is the code of a very simple react app:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Swiper test</h1>
      <div>
        <button className="swiper-button-prev"></button>
        <button className="swiper-button-next"></button>
        <Swiper
          style={{ width: 900, height: 300 }}
          spaceBetween={20}
          slidesPerView={3}
          navigation={{
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
          }}
        >
          <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
        </Swiper>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```